# Unrecognized option '-d2'

Tags: c#, opc-ua

This is the command that needs to be executed
Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -d2  -c[g]  -o2 :

```
.\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -d2 C:\Users\Downloads\DemoModel\DemoModelnew.xml -cg C:\Users\Downloads\DemoModel\DemoModelnew.csv" -o "C:\Users\Downloads\DemoModel\" -version v104
```

The error:

> [CommandParsingException] Unrecognized option '-d2' > (Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is not tech support. If you have a question about how to use a program, you should start by *reading the documentation* for that program. Stack Overflow is for questions about *code*.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **compile** after .\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe. The command would be the following in your case:

```
.\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe compile -d2 "C:\Users\Downloads\DemoModel\DemoModelnew.xml" -cg "C:\Users\Downloads\DemoModel\DemoModelnew.csv" -o "C:\Users\Downloads\DemoModel" -version v104
```